# Socket.IO not working in regular browser mode (but works in incognito)

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-client

I have to connect to Socket.IO server from my app.
I'm using Angular wrapper ngx-socket-io without any special options set.
I have noticed that everything works when I'm connecting in incognito mode - in regular mode I get "cannot connect exception".

I was compering requests in Chrome Dev console and I haven't seen any difference between them.
Have anyone noticed similar issues ?

Comment: What I have noticed additionally is when I block third party cookies in Chrome options - the connectivity start working - but I don't see any cookies in dev console so identification what is going is quite difficult